# Resize an image with height/width constraints and constant ratio

Tags: html, image-processing

I want to insert an image in a webpage and I want it to fit in a 120*40 space.
The problem is, original images can have about any size (400*40, 30*220, etc.)
so if I set height attribute to 40, I might find myself with images larger than 120 width. The same goes if I set a 120px width.
If I set both width to 120 and height to 40, well it fits, but the original ratio is lost, and I don't want that.

What would you suggest ?
Get the original properties of the image in javascript and then set one of them (either to 120 width or 40 height) so that the other fits in 120*40 ?
There are a lot images like that in one page so I think this method is a bit heavy...

PHP solution :

```
    <?php
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($image);
        if($width/$height>3)
            $height *= 120/$width;
        else 
            $height = 40;
?>
<img src="<?=$image?>" height=<?=$height?>>
```

see below for a javascript solution and a CSS solution

Comment: Are you using anything like PHP on the server side to dynamically determine the image width/height and set a class by the image characteristics?

Comment: yes I use PHP, with codeigniter as framework. you would leave it to a server side script ?

Comment: Well, I think you could, especially if caching was an option.

Comment: ok i'll investifate the PHP possibilities for this issue and post the code

Comment: see edited question for PHP solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

css properties `max-width` and `max-height` are what you need.

My guess is that it will resize itself if it reaches one of these.

I have used this alot in previous web projects.
But i havent used the combination of both yet.

EDIT: I've sais this in a comment, but setting both those properties does work in my tests. It keeps the ratio and resizes by the limit it reaches first. Do not set any `width` or `height` properties, these might cause problems

Comment: But `max-width` and `max-height` don't preserve the aspect ratio (i.e. the image is stretched).

Comment: nope, max-width and max-height don't work this way. They don't stick to any ratio :(

Comment: I tried out a few use cases and i couldn't find a mistake in this system. <img src="DSCN2630.JPG" style="max-height:100px; max-width:600px;"/> is what i tried, and it did resize in all my cases. Please tell me if i'm wrong, but I find this very curious. PS i tested in firefox 4.0, but normally that shouldn't be an issue. The image adjusts to the limit it reaches first, and keeps the ratio in my tests.

Comment: Also, do not set any height or width properties, just stick to the max-width and max-height properties...

Comment: all apologies, you are right (my problems were due to, on top of that, setting a width)

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is quite fast, so why not try it?

I'd just stick to finding the aspect ratio and adding some checks:

```
var width = image.width;
var height = image.height;
var ratio = width / height;

if (width > 120) {
  width = 120;
  height = 120 * ratio;
} else if (height > 80) {
  height = 80;
  width = 80 * ratio;
}

image.width = width + 'px';
image.height = height + 'px';
```

---

As you seem to be using PHP, ImageMagick can resize an image to fit inside of a predefined box. I only know how to do it via CLI, as I don't use PHP, but I bet the PHP code would be simple.

Comment: Why not? It's pseudo-code, as I don't care to test it, but it should.

Comment: no I mean : first I think you wanted to DIVIDE by the ratio (on the first if statement) ; then it would not gurantee that the image fits :  imagine a 140 width * 1200 height. wdith>120 so width is set to 120, and then height is set to 1000 something, and it does not fit in 120*80 :/

Comment: Lemme rework that logic. It doesn't account for the `height > width`.

Comment: @Blender, you have a slight flaw at the bottom with width/height. You don't want the `+ 'px';` in there. http://jsfiddle.net/vYutX/

Comment: ok simple : ratio is 120 width for 40 height : ideal ratio is 3. If an image has a >3 ratio, then height should be set to 40, else width to 120, html does the rest

Comment: (and I maintain : on the first if, it should be 120 DIVIDED by ratio)   http://jsfiddle.net/vYutX/5/

Comment: yup this one is good (except it won't resize images smaller than 120*40 to their optimal size) edit your answer and call it closed ?

Comment: So you want it to scale up too? I can try that.

Comment: perfect ! and I edited my question to display the PHP solution

Comment: Cool. Serverside is nicer for the user.

Comment: Note that the version I included in the fiddle I posted was simply the original solution with the `+ px` removed. The part that was the functional part was from the answer, though.

Answer (score 1):

I was actually searching for an answer to a different query but came across yours.

I use [this](http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/blog/resizing-images-with-php/) to resize images which I am finding is very handy in a number of my scripts, but what I would suggest is that you resize the image to a little bigger than the longest side of the container and then use css to center the image both horizontally and vertically and set the container with `overflow:hidden;`

You lose a small bit of the image around the edges but at least they are all inserted without any stretching or squashing.

Hope that helps you or anyone else trying something similar.